# (Scala) How to extend apply methods from an abstract class?

Tags: scala

I am hoping to save a lot of lines of code in my project by putting apply/unapply methods in the base abstract class. Is it possible to not write the apply method in the case classes, but instead in the abstract class?

The code I have written below will not actually work, but I believe it describes what I want to accomplish. The apply methods in the Animal class is not valid scala that will compile.

```
abstract class Animal(name:String,color:String,age:Int) {
  def apply(name:String, color:String, age:Int) = this(name,color,string) 
  def apply(name:String, color:String) = this(name,color,0) 
  def apply(name:String) = this(name,"",0) 
}

case class Rabbit(n:String,c:String,a:Int) extends Animal(n,c,a)
case class Squirrel(n:String,c:String,a:Int) extends Animal(n,c,a)
case class Dog(n:String,c:String,a:Int) extends Animal(n,c,a)
case class Cat(n:String,c:String,a:Int) extends Animal(n,c,a)

//(Ran elsewhere)
Rabbit("Billy")
Dog("Charlie","Brown",5)
Cat("Sprinkles","White")
```

Comment: You appear to have confused two different concepts: constructors (w/ auxiliary constructors) and `apply` methods.  This `bo = Dog("Bo")` uses a constructor (or auxiliary constructor) to create an instance of `Dog`. This `bo(7)` is a call to an `apply` method.  I don't think you can inherit auxiliary constructors.

Comment: No, this is a call to an `apply` method. Constructors are called using the `new` keyword.

Comment: Hint: what object are you calling the `apply` method on? What is its type? Where did you define the `apply` method?

Comment: I doubt that it is possible, but alternatively you could use default parameter values: `case class Rabbit(n: String, c: String = "", a: Int = 0) extends Animal(n, c, a)`.

Comment: @JörgWMittag, the `new` keyword is optional for case classes.  That's one of the advantages of case classes. `CaseClassName()` becomes the "factory method" to construct an instance of the class.  So far I am unable to demonstrate an example where `CaseClassName()` invokes an `apply()` method.

Comment: @jwvh: No, the `new` keyword is *not* optional for case classes. You are not calling the constructor, you are calling the companion object's `apply` method. Constructors are called with `new`. Period. If there's no `new`, there's not constructor. (Obviously any method may in turn call anything it likes, including constructors.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing first, you want your `apply` method to be on the companion object, not on the class itself, which allows you to call `Rabbit(...)`, as this is sugar for `Rabbit.apply`. With what you have, fixing the incorrect `this(...)` calls, you'd need an instance of `Animal` in order to call the apply methods.

Second, you seem to have jumbled `apply` and constructors together. In Scala, when you define a class, the parameters next to the name define the *primary constructor*. The body of the class then contains the body of the primary constructor. You may define *auxiliary constructors*, which look just like method definitions, except they don't return anything and are named `this`. This is an auxiliary constructor:

```
def this(qux: Qux) = {
  // Must call another constructor (super(...), this(...))
  this(qux.foobar)
  this.foo = qux.bar
}
```

You can *only* call a constructor (from outside another constructor) using the `new` keyword. **There is no other way to call a constructor.** (Unless, duh, you call a method that calls a constructor (or reflection (ew)).) When you do `Foo(5)`, you aren't calling the constructor directly, you are calling `Foo.apply(5)`, on the companion object. For an ordinary class `Bar`, doing `Bar(...)` will fail, unless the companion object has defined an `apply` method.

Enter `case class`es. The Scala compiler will insert certain helper methods into both the class itself and it's companion when it encounters one. The Big Two, surprise surprise, are `apply`, which creates objects with the syntax `Foo(...)`, and its evil twin `unapply`, which decomposes the object for pattern matching. The compiler only generates an `apply` method for the primary constructor, and it has the exact same signature.

So it looks like we can't do anything with just the constructors, so let's move on to somehow automatically putting `apply` methods into the companion object. One way to do this would be macros, but that's way too complicated for this. The other way, in which we define a trait that you mix in to the companion object would require reflection and would be complicated too, and would require two lines per class, one for the `class`, one for the `object`. So now what?

Enter default parameters! This is, in fact, practically a textbook case for default parameters. (Sorry for beating around the bush.) Define the base class `Animal`:

```
abstract class Animal(name: String, color: String, age: Int)
```

Now, for each derived class, in the constructor, use default parameters. Default parameters are of the form `$arg: $type = $default`, or basically a normal parameter with an "equals something" tacked on. Here the defaults seem to be `color = ""` and `age = 0`.

```
case class Rabbit(name: String, color: String = "", age: Int = 0) extends Animal(name, color, age)
```

Now, the expression `new Rabbit("Fooey", "white")` will be translated into `new Rabbit("Fooey", "white", 0)`. (Not really, but close enough.) This is also true for the `apply` method. Note, however, this does not exactly define the functionality of your "example." It is possible to define `age` without defining `color`, like so: `Rabbit("Pit", age = 2)` sets `age` to `2`, and defaults `color` to `""`

**TL;DR** default parameters

Comment: Thank you. I am now using default parameters in my project.